# How to update royalty wallets on a whole collection?

Tags: metaplex, solana-program, metadata, nft

I am trying to update the royalty wallets on a collection. I have been able to upload my metadata and make new uri with different royalty wallets + % on ardrive and update an individual nft through metaboss but doing this for thousands would take forever is there any quick way around this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The royalty wallets of your NFTs are stored on-chain, so you have to update each NFT that is part of the collection individually, because each NFT has its own on-chain creator array. You can use metaboss to make this simple.

So the steps to follow, assuming that your NFTs has the mutable flag on, are:

1. You need to run [`metaboss decode mint`](https://metaboss.rs/decode.html#decode-mint) in order to get all ur NFTs onchain metadata on a output directory (one file per NFT).
2. You have to create a basic script that iterate over each file inside that directory in order to change the creator array to the new creator array that you wanna have (make sure to not change the first creator if you used a Candy machine to create the NFT). You can change any other onchain attribute here too, like the royalty %, name, uri, etc.
3. You have to run [`metaboss update data-all`](https://metaboss.rs/update.html#update-data-all) providing the updated files and thats it.

Be really carefull and make sure that you understand what it is stored onchain and remember that making something wrong while updating can create some disaster on the NFTs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply homie, But when i check my URI metadata thats where it shows the royalty wallets and different shares not on-chain ?

Comment: The off-chain metadata and on-chain metadata are completly different things. It doesnt matter what is showing off-chain (on the uri), the important thing is that the on-chain metadata is updated

Comment: Step 2 can be made easier. You dont need a script, you can also just use search and replace content of all files in a folder e.g. with vscode.

Also there is a function update-creators-all now which might be easier than decoding, changing and updating https://metaboss.rs/update.html#update-creators-all